# Can I pipe clipboard content to browser for viewing?

Tags: command-line, browser, xsel

Here is the situation.

I often have to read chunks of information from large plain text files. I am planning to use  [Readability](https://www.readability.com/addons/) extension for formating the content to make it readable on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xclip` to paste the contents to a temporary file and then open that file with firefox. For example:

```
temp=$(mktemp); xclip -o > $temp; firefox "$temp"
```

- `mktemp` generates a temporary file in `/tmp`,
- `xclip -o` pastes the contents of the clipboard to that file,
- and at least `firefox` open that file as if it were a website.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't let you conveniently paste HTML. You can [save it in a file and browse that file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226945).

Alternatively, you can make a file that serves the clipboard content when you read it, and point your browser to that. One way to do that is through the [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem [scriptfs](https://github.com/frodonh/scriptfs).

Create a one¹-liner to print the clipboard content:

```
#!/bin/sh
xsel -o -b
```

Put it in a directory of its own, call it `clipboard.html` and make it executable. Mount the directory with scriptfs:

```
mkdir /path/to/xclip.d
scriptfs /path/to/directory-with-clipboard.html /path/to/xclip.d
firefox /path/to/xclip.d/clipboard.html
```

¹  <sub>Two with the shebang.</sub>